# Best way to display top level list

Tags: android, list, listview, expandablelistview

I am working on my first Android application.  Right now it uses fragments to separate between the main sections of the app (error code lookup and deal of the week are my fragments) and I now want to create a third fragment for some of our common programming information.  In the programming information I will have several brands (of equipment we use) that will then display a lot of details (which phone number, port, SSL options, etc, we will use).

I was looking at ExpandableListview thinking maybe that might be the best way, but wondered if there might be another option.  Mostly because I don't like the way the ExpandableListView looks.  It feels very outdated compared to the rest of my UI using Holo and ActionBar.

Any suggestions?  I would love almost like a "sub-fragment" layout if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look for libs in github.

There is a lot of diferent way of displaying things... like :

StiskyListHeaders by emilsjolander
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

....

You can see most of the libs curently used and stable in the app : "Libraries for developers"
It's on the store